# Specialize a non-type template function with several values and the same specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I mean to have a templated function that depends on a `size_t` template parameter.
I have a "fallback" definition, placed in my `sfinae.h`.

```
template <size_t dim>
int sumVec(void) {
    return -1;
}
```

I already have a couple of specializations for specific values of `dim`, e.g. in my `sfinae.cc`,

```
template <>
int sumVec<2>(void) {
    return 2;
};
```

and its prototype in `sfinae.h`.

Now I want to define one specialization that applies for several values of `dim`, so I mean to avoid having to replicate it several times.
I could make `dim` into an `enum class`, as done in [One template specialization for several enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523928/one-template-specialization-for-several-enum-values)

My question is
**Can I achieve my objective without (heavily) changing the code I have (but I could add to it)?**

I tried adding code below either in the header or the source, and the compiler (gcc 10.2.0) threw an error `non-class, non-variable partial specialization 'sumVec<std::enable_if<((dim == 3) || (dim == 4)), void> >' is not allowed`
so I am not sure I am not using the right approach or syntax, or what I asked is not allowed by the compiler.

```
template<size_t dim>
int sumVec<std::enable_if<dim == 3 || dim == 4>>(void)
{
    return dim;
};
```

Comment: You could probably just have one class and use `if constexpr` in its implementation, depends what you're trying to actually achieve

Comment: Not without changing sfinae.h.

Comment: @AlanBirtles - So far I don't have any class. 
I welcome you posting a brief example of what you have in mind.
As for what I am after, it would be long to explain, and I am not certain it changes the question... I guess this should not be taken as an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), I am currently interested in the posted MCVE... please let me know if it is not clear enough.

Comment: @bipll - See updated OP... I meant not to change it substantially.

Answer (score 1):

Function templates can't be partial specialized. You can apply SFINAE by overloading, which requires to change the primary template to avoid ambiguous calling.

```
// primary template overloading #1
template<size_t dim>
std::enable_if_t<dim != 3 && dim != 4, int> sumVec(void)
{
    return -1;
}

// primary template overloading #2
template<size_t dim>
std::enable_if_t<dim == 3 || dim == 4, int> sumVec(void)
{
    return dim;
}

// full specialization
template <>
int sumVec<2>(void) {
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: This works, if placed everything in the header.
What would the correct way to place definitions in a source, leaving only prototypes in the header?
I tried declaring `inline` several combinations, but I am not getting the rationale to decide the correct one.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio It's not easy to accomplish. [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3309790)

Comment: I was aware of it, and I have actually upvoted it in the past.
But I have used explicit instantiations in the source elsewhere, e.g.
Moreover, here my `sumVec<2>` is defined in the source. But I could not manage to define the two `std::enable_if_t...` in the source.
I guess with a suitable selection of `inline`s (which I did not get) it should work.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Primary templates have to be visible in every translation unit where they're used, I think they have to be placed in hearder and included if necessary. BTW: If you place the specialization in cc file, which is not included, i.e. invisible in the translation unit then the primary template would be called instead.

Comment: "Function templates can't be partial specialized." Not exactly true. You can get _some_ degree of partial specialization with `if constexpr` in the primary definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid template specialisations with `if constexpr` and just have a single instance of your class:

```
template <size_t dim>
int sumVec(void) {
    if constexpr (dim == 2) {
       return 2;
    }
    if constexpr (dim == 3 || dim == 4) {
       return dim;
    }
    return -1;
}
```